# Type inference using class expresions on Protege

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I was hoping I could defined `Elective_Course` in such a way that all individuals that are `partOf` a `Knowledge_Unit` and are not of type `Core_Course` are `Elective_Course`s.

For `Course` I have this:

[image]

I thought maybe something on the lines of `(partOf only Knowledge_unit) and not(Core_Course)` would do the trick, but it doesn't work.

Maybe it is because I need and `only` with the inverse property of `partOf`, but I haven't defined that property since I didn't need it for the rest. So I could say in `Knowledge_Unit` that `hasPart only Course` and then `not(Core_Course)` on the `Elective_Course`.

But I'm lost, so any help or links to examples are welcome.

The full ontology is available [here](https://github.com/lsarni/CISOnto/blob/fix/rdf-transform/curricula.owl)

Comment: Please post your complete ontology rather than images. It is difficult to figure out what you are trying to achieve from partial information.

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse I have included a link to the full ontology

Comment: OWL = Open World Assumption, this is important to know

Comment: @moondaisy I have updated my answer to include a reference to understanding universal property restrictions which may explain why your ontology is not behaving as you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is due to the open world assumption in OWL and Description Logics. This means the reasoner will only infer new inferences from explicitly stated information and **not** from absence of information.

So to achieve your desired result you have to state that `Core_Course` and `Elective_Course` are disjoint. Then you can do one of two things:

(1) State for each individual that is an elective that it is of type `not 
(Core_Course)`. But then you could just as well state it as of type `Elective_Course`.

(2) Define all your knowledge unit individuals as say `core1, core2, ... coren, elective1, elective2, ..., electivek`. Then set `Knowledge_Unit` equivalent to all individuals and `Core_Course` to all core course individuals, i.e.

```
 Class: Knowledge_Unit
   EquivalentTo: {core1, core2, ... coren, elective1, elective2, ..., electivek}
 Class: Core_Course
    SubClassOf: Knowledge_Unit,
    EquivalentTo: {core1, core2, ... coren}
```

**Update: 20180510**

Wrt universal property restrictions like `partOf only KnowledgeUnit`, it is important to understand that it also includes individuals for which it is known that they do not take part in any `partOf` relation. This can lead to entailments that can be difficult to understand. I have written about this [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/05/10/understanding-owl-universal-property-restrictions/).

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation in the post, I have been going through the other posts but still struggle with most things :)

Comment: The underlying theory can be difficult to understand, even for experienced ontology designers, so don't be too hard on yourself :-) It is good that you ask and keep on struggling with it. It is the only way it will really start to make sense to you eventually. Not because of you but because it is actually difficult.