# OWL Protegé: Using the same Object property for different Domains/Ranges

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, object-properties

I'm using Protegé to create an OWL ontology and I have Question.

I have the following set up:

```
        (relation1)
ClassA isTriggeredBy ClassB

        (relation1)
ClassC isTriggeredBy ClassD
```

Nevertheless the relation should be either (ClassA, ClassB) or (ClassC,ClassD). I don't want combinations like (ClassA, ClassD) to be possible since it makes no sense from the ontology semantic perspective. I tried to avoid that by specifying the following in the **Object Property Description** of relation1 *isTriggeredBy*:

```
Domain (intersection)
ClassA or ClassC

Ranges (intersection)
ClassB or ClassD
```

and I added local constraints in both **Class Description** of *ClassA* and *ClassC*:

```
Description:ClassA
SubClass Of
isTriggeredBy some ClassB

Description:ClassC
SubClass of
isTriggeredBy some ClassD
```

But I don't know if this is correct. Moreover I don't know if this the more appropriate way to do this or if it necessary to create different object properties.

Thanks for the attention and support,

pLs

Comment: You may also want to look at [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961407/type-inference-using-class-expresions-on-protege/49963090#49963090) that I answered.

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking at it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, it is important to understand the reason for using domain and range restrictions. If have

```
ObjectProperty: isTriggeredBy
  Domain: A
  Range: B
```

what you want to achieve is that whenever you know that an individual `a` is related via `isTriggeredBy` to individual `b`, the reasoner can infer that `a` is of type `A` and `b` is of type `B`.

If you have

```
ObjectProperty: isTriggeredBy
  Domain: ClassA or ClassC
  Range: ClassB or ClassD
```

it can at most infer that individual `a` is of type `ClassA or ClassC` and individual `b` is of type `ClassB or ClassD`. That is even with the added axioms

```
Class:ClassA
  SubClassOf: isTriggeredBy some ClassB

Class:ClassC
  SubClassOf:isTriggeredBy some ClassD
```

you will **not** get to differentiate between the relations (`ClassA`, `ClassB`) and (`ClassC`,`ClassD`).

A way to achieve this differentiation is to use subproperties:

```
ObjectProperty: isTriggeredBy
  Domain: ClassA or ClassC
  Range: ClassB or ClassD

ObjectProperty: isTriggeredByB
  SubPropertyOf: isTriggeredBy
  Domain: ClassA
  Range:ClassB

ObjectProperty: isTriggeredByD
  SubPropertyOf: isTriggeredBy
  Domain: ClassC
  Range:ClassD
```

Then when you have an individual `a` that is associated via `isTriggeredByB` to individual `b`, it will infer that `a` is of type `ClassA` and `b` is of type `ClassB`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I really appreciate that. 
Do you think this is the best alternative or it is better to create 2 diferentes object properties with no sub-properties?

Comment: It depends on the needs of your application domain. If you need to know that `isTriggeredByB` and `isTriggeredByD` are `isTriggeredBy` relations, then you need to define them as subproperties. If you don't need to know that, you can just have the 2 properties without being subproperties of `isTriggeredBy`.

Comment: Are you trying to translate UML class diagrams to OWL by any chance?

Comment: I'm not. But I'm trying to define a ubiquitous language terminology related to my application domain using ontology. So I'm trying to keep the ontology terminology as close to the domain terminology as possible.

Comment: Ok, well in that case you probably need to know that `isTriggeredByB` and `isTriggeredByD` are `isTriggeredBy` relations.

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer as correct? Thanks!

Comment: On my blog I write about modelling issues in OWL, which might be of interest to you. You can also ask questions there if you like. See https://henrietteharmse.com.

Comment: I will check now. Again, thanks for collaboration and detailed explanation. Any doubts I will post here =]